# Overstaying grace period and reentering on an ESTA

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying

My visa got cut short, and I kept my original plans which ended over a week after the grace period. I then reapplied for a visa, was granted one, and visited another few times. My visa is no longer valid and I would like to travel on an ESTA. Will I have any problems?

Comment: What has changed that you don't need a visa and are able to use Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: What do you mean "My visa got cut short"? Visas are only for entry. How long you can stay in the US is determined by the date on your I-94 and the conditions of your status. Also, since you are saying "grace period", are you talking about F or J status? Those have "grace periods" after finishing the program; other statuses are admitted until a certain fixed date.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly try applying for an ESTA, making sure to answer all of the questions truthfully.

If your ESTA is approved, then you are free to travel to the US.  If your ESTA is refused then you will need to apply for a visa.

As is always the case, having an approved ESTA (or even Visa) is not a guarantee that you will be allowed enter the country, but almost certainly you will have no problems presuming you answered the questions in the ESTA application truthfully.